# Importing huge XML into Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, postgresql, xml-parsing, sidekiq

I have a huge (over 700mb) XML file with entries that i need to add to db. I used Nokogiri to iterate over nodes and save it to db. It took almost a day. Then i added sidekiq gem, created workers and reduced time to 5 hours.
Strange thing is that after a hour or so it slows down. At start my configuration creates about 100 entries/second, and then slows to 20-50 for the rest of the process.
The problem is that i cant find bottleneck and why is it slows. Need help

Ruby 1.9.3 + Rails 4.0.3 + PostgreSQL + Redis + sidekiq + Nokogiri

Nokogiri iterator:

```
doc.xpath('data/entries/entry').each do |entry|
  product = {
    sid: entry.at_css('sid').content,
    title: entry.at_css('title').content,
    description: entry.at_css('description').content
  }

  EntryWorker.perform_async product
end
```

Worker:

```
class EntryWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform hash
    hash.symbolize_keys!     
    sid = hash[:sid]

    product = Product.where(sid: sid).first_or_initialize
    product.assign_attributes(hash)

    product.save!
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using Nokogiri in SAX mode and **not** using ActiveRecord at all? Then chunk your INSERTs into 1000 or so and do each chunk inside its own PostgreSQL transaction.

Comment: What happens if you just comment out the part that inserts it into the database?  That is an easy way to figure out where the bottleneck is.